# Hibernate passing a null connection to doReturningWork

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Intermittently hibernate is passing me a null connection in this execute method

```
return session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<MyIterator<MyVO>>() {

@Override
MyIterator<MyVO> execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String preparedSql = "EXEC MyDB.dbo.MySP ?, ?"; 
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(preparedSql); // <-- NPE !
```

The app is running in tomcat and connecting through a firewall with ports opened to SQL Server.

Any idea why that could be - here is my connection pool config

```
<Resource name="xxx"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
username="username"
password="password"                        
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
maxActive="200"
maxIdle="0"
maxWait="1000"
initialSize="1"
minIdle="0"
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
url="jdbc:sqlserver://IP\INST\databasename"
SelectMethod="cursor"
validationQuery="select 1"
testOnBorrow="true"
logAbandoned="true"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="600"/>
```